# Bluetooth Data loss on Oreo

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-8.0-oreo

My app gets data from Bluetooth module and I get losses only on Android 8.0. On 7.0 and 8.1.2, things are fine.

Someone told me it could be the compatibility issue between Broadcom 
BT chip and Android 8.0.

I have done some testing on Galaxy S8 (Android 8.0) and LG G6 (Android 8.0) and confirmed that the data loss were apparent on those devices.

On LG V40 (Android 8.1.2) and some tablet (Android 7.0), the data loss did not happen.

I am trying to confirm whether the problem happens on all Android 8.0 devices or only on Android 8.0 devices with Broadcom chip.

If you happen to know anything, feel free to comment or answer!

Thank you

Comment: Probably not a software API issue if you are suspecting different Bluetooth performance issue between phones. However, how you do manage the assembly of the data packets received from a Bluetooth socket? Do you have a specific high-level data protocol? What kind of data? What kind of Bluetooth profile are you using for your app?

Comment: @ecle I am using Blutooth SPP profile. After connection thread is forked, RFComm socket is made as in android reference sample (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth?hl=ko)

Comment: I don't have any Android 8 device to verify this issue except Android 7 and below. Currently, I have successfully implemented Bluetooth SPP profile for my BT remote control app with this [LM 048BT RS232 module](https://www.lm-technologies.com/product/bluetooth-serial-adapter-class-1-lm048/). But, for BT support, the app manages it as a Service which maintains the BT connection in the background and properly disconnects/reconnects it every time the app orientation changes.